# ethernet interface, ethernet adapter or bluetooth adapter?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, ethernet, bluetooth

I am running Linux Mint 17.3 and I am a little bit confused with some network terminology.
The output of the `ifcongif` is as follows:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet ...
```

and the output from `tcpdump --list-interfaces` is:

```
1.bluetooth0 (Bluetooth adapter number 0)
```

So actually it appears that the eth0-interface is using the bluetooth-technology to contact with the modem. or?

As far as I know the bluetooth-technology has been used for wireless connections but not for wired ones and the ethernet-technology has been used for cable (wired) connections.

Does my network card is using both technologies simultaneously?

Answer (score 1):

according to wikipedia ethernet is this:

> Ethernet divide a stream of data into shorter pieces called frames.
>   Each frame contains source and destination addresses, and
>   error-checking data so that damaged frames can be detected and
>   discarded; most often, higher-layer protocols trigger retransmission
>   of lost frames. As per the OSI model, Ethernet provides services up to
>   and including the data link layer.[4] Features such as the 48-bit MAC
>   address and Ethernet frame format have influenced other networking
>   protocols including Wi-Fi wireless networking technology

So the Ethernet protocol/frame part of any network communication.  It doesn't matter if it is wired or wireless.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. The problem is that when you run the command 'tcpdump --list-interfaces' the output you receive will be '1.bluetooth0 (Bluetooth adapter number 0)'.

But actually this is only the one of all network interfaces you have on your Linux-Mint machine.

To receive the full list of all network interfaces you should run 'tcpdump --list-interfaces' as a root user. So the correct command should be 'sudo tcpdump --list-interfaces' and ... voila!